# Argocd Notification controller Fails to push alerts to opsgenie

Tags: argocd

I am trying to send the sync failure alerts to Opsgenie but its failing with below error

> INFO[2023-09-12T16:05:48.681439155Z] Client is configured with ApiUrl: >https://api.opsgenie.com/v2/alerts, LogLevel: info, RetryMaxCount: 4
> ERRO[2023-09-12T16:05:48.681507441Z] Request validation err: message can not be empty'

Below is the configuration that i have done in argocd value file

```
template.app-sync-failed: |
      opsgenie:
        message: "ArgoCD Notification - Sync Failure for {{.app.metadata.name}}"
        description: "An ArgoCD application {{.app.metadata.name}} in project {{.app.spec.project}} has experienced a sync failure. Sync status: {{.app.status.sync.status}}"
        priority: "P2"
        tags:
          - "argocd"
          - "notification"
        details:
          "Sync Status": "{{.app.status.sync.status}}"
          "Synced at": "{{.app.status.operationState.finishedAt}}"
          "App Health": "{{.app.status.health.status}}"
          "Revisions": "{{.app.status.sync.revisions}}"
          "Sync Initiator": "{{.app.status.operationState.operation.initiatedBy}}"
          "Conditions":
            {{range $index, $c := .app.status.conditions}}
              {{if not $index}},{{end}}
              {{if $index}},{{end}}
              {
                "Type": "{{$c.type}}",
                "Message": "{{$c.message}}"
              }
            {{end}}
      teams:
        facts: |
          [{
            "name": "Sync Status",
            "value": "{{.app.status.sync.status}}"
          },
          {
            "name": "Synced at",
            "value": "{{.app.status.operationState.finishedAt}}"
          },
          {
            "name": "App Health",
            "value": "{{.app.status.health.status}}"
          },
          {
            "name": "Revisions",
            "value": "{{.app.status.sync.revisions}}"
          },
          {
            "name": "Sync Initiator",
            "value": "{{.app.status.operationState.operation.initiatedBy}}"
          }
          {{range $index, $c := .app.status.conditions}}
            {{if not $index}},{{end}}
            {{if $index}},{{end}}
            {
              "name": "{{$c.type}}",
              "value": "{{$c.message}}"
            }
          {{end}}
          ]
        themeColor: '#660000'
        title: Application {{.app.metadata.name}} sync FAILURE
        text: Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has failed sync operation at {{.app.status.operationState.finishedAt}}.
```

I am able to successfully receive alerts on teams channel. But for Opsgenie it is not working. Please let me know what mistake i am doing here.

Answer (score 1):

the place of the message field is wrong. It should be like this:

```html
  template.opsgenie: |
    message: Application {{.app.metadata.name}} is {{.app.status.health.status}}.
    opsgenie:
      description: test
```